# Is there a way to deal with values which are the same in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have managed to make a program where I would read data from excel files and store them in tables in mysql. My program read the first row of each file create the fields for the tables and store the rest data as values in each columns. Just because that happen programmatically I have choosed to read all the values using LinkedHashMap. Everything works fine. But when I finished and test my program I get an error in my console. After a few days of looking for it atd while I was trying to solve it I read in the documentation of LinkedHashMap that "if the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced". And my hole program destroyed at once. The reason is that in my files I have values that are the same in some columns. 
Does someone knows if there is a way to solve this problem or I have to start my program from the beginning? Since I have little time for this could you please help me finding a way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not a problem, it's how Maps work, one key = one value, it's the contract. You should use a List with a custom class or a pair.

Comment: You can create a map like this: `Map<Key, List<Value>>` and store objects with same keys in a list

Comment: It's very unclear what your key/value pairs are here. Normally I'd expect the data to be read into a `List<Row>` for some `Row` type. You might want to look at Guava's `LinkedHashMultimap` though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Maps work, you have the wrong container here, you probably want a list with a custom class or a Map of List:

```
public class Data
{  
    private String d1;
    private String d2;

    public Date (String d1, String d2)
    {
        ...
    }  
    public parsedDataType getD1()... //might be the string, or an number, or something else
    ... 
}

public void read()
{
    ...
    List<Data> data = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
    Data d = new Data(d1,d2);
    data.add(d);
}
```

Or you can use a Map of List as suggested by svz:

```
Map<String,List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(d1);
list.add(d2);
data.put(myKey,list);
```

The adventage with a list of class is that you can then process your data inside (verifications etc.)